# one instance affects another although it shouldn't

Tags: c++, matrix, instantiation

I made a matrix class MxN of type T and tried to instantiate and print it.
A problem rose up that you see at the end of the code (when I did `cout << m;`)
That command printed out a matrix with some fields of another matrix - actually the first column of `m` is the same as the last column of `m2` and I don't get it why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;


template<typename T, int M>
class matrix_helper {
public:
    T& operator[](int j) {
        return data[j];
    }

private:
    T data[M];  
};

template<typename T, int N, int M>
class matrix {
public:
    explicit matrix(const vector<T>& v) {
        if (v.size() != M * N)
            throw invalid_argument("Incorrect input data");

        int i=0, j=0;

        for (int k = 0; k != M*N; ++k) {
            data[i][j] = v[k];
            ++i;
            if (i == M) { // i:0..M
                i = 0;
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
    matrix_helper<T,M> operator[](int j) {
        matrix_helper<T, M> mh;
        for(int i=0; i != M; ++i) {
            mh[i] = data[j][i];
        }
        return mh;
    }
    matrix<T,M,N>& operator+=(matrix<T,M,N>& m) {
        for(int i=0; i != N;++i)
            for(int j=0; j != M;++j) {
                this->data[i][j] += m[i][j]; // or - should I rather use (*this)[i][j] += ... ???
            }

        return *this;
    }

private:
    T data[N][M];
};

template<typename T, int N, int M>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, matrix<T,N,M> & m) {
        int i=0, j=0;
        for (int k = 0; k != M*N; ++k) {
            os << m[i][j] << '\t';
            ++i;
            if (i == M) { // i:0..M
                i = 0;
                ++j;
                os << endl;
            }
        }
        os << endl;
}



int rnd(int max = 20) { return rand() % max; }
void print(int i) { cout << i << ' '; }

int main() {

    vector<int> u, v; 
    for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i) u.push_back(i);

    for (int i = 20; i != 40; ++i) v.push_back(i);
    //for_each(u.begin(), u.end(), print);


    matrix<int, 4,5> m(u);
    matrix<int, 4,5> m2(v);
    cout << m; // returns: 24 1 2 3 4,... Why not 0 1 2 3 4 ???


    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks. Didn't know codereview. I'll wait a couple of minutes and if I get no answer I will post it there...

Comment: Codereview isn't for asking "why doesn't this do what I think it does".

Comment: @Tomy - You use `matrix<T,M,N>` in some places and `matrix<T,N,M>` in others. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Your output function doesn't return the output stream. Surprised you don't get an error about it.

Comment: Btw, in your `operator<<`, why do you have a single complicated for-loop that runs until `M*N`? Why not just have two nested for loops? You didn't magically reduce the complexity by doing that, you know? you're still executing the same number of steps (actually, there a few extra steps in your implementation).

Comment: Paul Manta: I just copied the code from the ctor...didn't want to magically reduce complexity :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare an array of `[N][M]`, but your initialization code treats it as if it were `[M][N]`.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you see values from m2 in m is because your matrix ctor is writing outside of data array bounds overwriting anything there is on the stack in near proximity. Exactly this line:

```
data[i][j] = v[k];
```

writes outside of array bounds.

also your

```
ostream& operator<< ()
```

should return value

Answer (score -1):

You need to allocate memory to matrix::data array.

You could modify like this,

`T data[N][M];`  =>  `std::vector< std::vector<T> > data;`

Then prepared vectors in the constructor,

```
data.assign(M, std::vector<T>());
for (int x=0; x<M; ++x)
    data[x].assign(N, T());
```